# Batch and the for loop

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath

I have a java application launched by a .cmd file. I want to set the classpath of the application through this batch, all the needed jars are into a lib folder.

Here is what I tried :

```
 set _classpath=.
for %%i in (%1/lib/*.*) do ( set _classpath=%_classpath%;%%i )
```

Surprisingly, it seems that it does not act as expected. Let's say there is 3 jar in the lib folder :

- pikachu.jar
- sonic.jar
- mario.jar

Here is what happens :

1. set _classpath=.
2. set _classpath=.;pikachu.jar
3. set _classpath=.;sonic.jar
4. set _classpath=.;mario.jar

Obviously, what I am looking to get is

- set
  _classpath=.;pikachu.jar;sonic.jar;mario.jar

Any idea ?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Why do you need a batch file to include classpath?  Have you seen the new Java 6 trick `-cp "lib/*"`  That would include all jars in the lib directory

Comment: Unfortunately, need to use java 5... But thanks for that, will definitely be useful for java 6 projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this at the top of your batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Then inside the for loop, replace `%_classpath%` with `!_classpath!`

Without delayed expansion enabled, `%_classpath%` gets expanded once, at the beginning of your for loop.

---

**[Edit]** In response to a comment, here is a full code-listing

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set _classpath=.
for %%i in (%1/lib/*.*) do (
    set _classpath=!_classpath!;%%i
)

echo %_classpath%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks BlueRaja (Thanks Richard as well.), there is another issue coming up when using this approach. I can see that the classpath looks something similar to that at the end of the loop :

.;pikachu.jar ;sonic.jar ;mario.jar  

The spaces are inexpected and will hurt. Do you know a quick way to get rid of them ? I suppose we could do a right trim on  %%i ?

Comment: @Farid: It's because you have a space at the end of your block. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

`CMD.EXE` is expanding the `%...%` before running the loop.

You need delayed variable expansion, this is explained in `set /?` from a command prompt.